# Custom tooltips

Tags: css

Is there anyway of customizing all tool tips through title tag without having to add classes or span etc.

Basically just show custom tooltip whenever the title=""  tag is used

The following demo adds tooltip class to all the fields found in a given form, however i cant make it work with my website for some unknown reason which i have given up on.

http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/form.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS3 to [target the title element](http://www.css3.info/preview/attribute-selectors/) `p[title^="ho"] {background: green;}` and [create javascript-less tooltips](http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-tooltips).

This would allow you to programmatically add tips using only CSS, but you would have to have a jQuery or javascript fallback for older browsers.